# Cinnamon moves all windows to primary monitor when unlocking screen

Tags: cinnamon, multi-monitor, screen-lock

I run Cinnamon with two 4K monitors.

Every time I unlock my screen, all open windows move back the primary monitor.

How can I make these existing windows remember their position?

This is a desktop computer; the monitors are never disconnected.

Comment: Fill a [bugreport](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues)